# to set button text at runtime with already set text

Tags: android

I want to display arraylist size in buttonText .Button text already set in xml file as "SHOW" . I want that "show(size of array)".
how to do this.
I already got the size of array in a variable named size as below.

```
public int CountRecord(ImageItemBin bin)
{
    showImagelist.add(showBin);
    int size=showImagelist.size();
    tvcounter.setText(Integer.toString(size));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tvcounter.setText("Show " + size);`

Comment: thanks a lot. I used like this.                                             btnShow.setText("Show ( "+Integer.toString(size)+ " ) ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a batter way using `strings.xml`
All you have to do is create a new string in string xml with `%s` sign
for example (`%s` for string value `%d` for int value )

```
 <string name="button_text_show">show %d</string>
```

now in your java code you do something like this

```
btnShow.setText(getString(R.string.button_text_show,size));
```

This will add size to your previous show text .`%d`is an kind of an indicator that some digit value will come here.

Answer (score 0):

set like this

```
tvcounter.setText(size+"");
```

or

```
tvcounter.setText(String.valueOf(size));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to this code..

```
public int CountRecord(ImageItemBin bin) {
    showImagelist.add(showBin);
    int size = showImagelist.size();
    String set = String.valueOf(size);
    tvcounter.setText(set);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
tvCounter.setText(mButton.getText().toString() + Integer.toString(size));
```